# Hiding Parameters in url while sending url through response.sendRedirect method

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, post, get

I am sending url to another server through `response.sendRedirect()` method and it is generating pdf for me. I am passing all the parameters but one of the parameter data is exceeding length due to which browser is not able to handle it and request is getting blocked.

I know through Post method we can hide url Parameters and `response.sendRedirect()` uses `GET` method. Is there any `POST` method like `sendRedirect` through which we can access another server url directly through servlet? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use RequestDispatcher for forwarding your request
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("your server controller");

Comment: @CHERUKURI I think this is used for requesting the controller on the same system,not other system.As I have to send request to different server.

Comment: No you can't. A possible hack is to forward to a page where you put the post data into a form and submit the form as soon as the page is loaded

Answer (score 0):

With `response.sendRedirect(newUrl)` you send back a HTTP status `302` with a new `Location=newUrl` in response header. Thus, you cannot force browser to make POST instead of GET method.

What you could do is to consume a pdf file from within your server code and return it to the client, hiding thus from client the actual target location. You can then build any request with method and parameters you want to the new location if it accept it.

See, for example, this tutorial how to make a request to another server from your servlet http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/

Comment: I have this PDF generation code in client server only.What we are doing is taking parameters from our database and passing . But as I told one parameter is getting huge due to which browser is unable to handle.

Comment: Your Servlet can use a HttpURLConnection  object to make a post request. Once you have the data, you can stream it to your client.

Comment: Let me clear it. You take a request from client browser, read needed parameters from request, get something from database, build a new URL (which exceeds some size limitaions) and send it back to the client with response.sendRedirect(newUrl). Is it right?

Comment: @olexd . you are almost right ... we are just making getting variables from database, build a new URL (which exceeds some size limitaions) and send it back to the client with response.sendRedirect(newUrl).

Comment: So, instead of sending an URL back to the browser, retrieve pdf data by this URL directly in your servlet code and send back to the browser its content. Thus, browser get back from your servlet a complete PDF file and not an URL to retrieve this pdf. Benefits of such approach - you can operate with a request to PDF-server as you wish/can.